# PHP can I do a hash of arrays?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I'm currently trying to create a hash table of arrays like so:

```
joe
   => 1
   => 2
pete
   => 1
   => 3
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$name = array(); 

while(my condition statement) { 
    if (preg_match("/(.+?)\s*\-\s*(.+?)/", $info)) {                

        list($name, $number) = split('\s*\-\s*', $info);                
        array_push($name,$number);

    }
}

$_SESSION['info'] = $name;
```

My outout looks like this:

```
[0] => 1 [1] => 2
```

Why is the name not showing up?

I know in Perl I've always done something like this:

```
while() {
    push @{$hash{$name}}, $number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

correctly specify the index:

```
$array['joe'][] = 1;
$array['joe'][] = 2;
$array['pete'][] = 1;
...
```

in your example something like:

```
$array[$name][] = $number;
```

though I don't really get your code as you overwrite $name in the while loop.

Comment: that was my mistake creating the example

Comment: That did the trick! I have never used that syntax before, more specifically the empty brackets

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array(); 

// [...]

list($name, $number) = split('\s*\-\s*', $info);
$names[$name][] = $number;
```